# Cannot find symbol.. (a.volume is erroe and shoen in compiler as cannot find symbol pls help)

Tags: java, symbols

```
class Method
{   double w,h,d;
    double volume(double w,double h,double d)
    {
        return (h*w*d);
    }
}

class Methodtwo

{

    public static void main(String args [])

    {
        Method a= new Method();
        a.volume(2,3,4);
        double v;
        v=a.volume;
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. You should know that you have created an object of the `Method` class, called `a`. You are invoking it's function, `volume` with the parameters `(2,3,4)`. This will return a value but, you don't use it. Instead you attempt to store in variable v, the value stored in a parameter `volume` that is in `Method`. Well, `Method` doesn't even have a parameter called `volume`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write something like this:

```
  v = a.volume(2, 3, 4);
```

Because a is an instance `volume` should be a method .
And try this [learn java](http://www.learnjavaonline.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Double check your Methodtwo class. You called `v=a.volume;` and that's wrong, because the `volume()` method needs three parameters. Check the corrected code.

```
class Method
{   double w,h,d;
    double volume(double w,double h,double d)
    {
        return (h*w*d);
    }
}

class Methodtwo

{

    public static void main(String args [])

    {
        Method a= new Method();
        double v = a.volume(2,3,4);
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that you are not saving the result of the method "volume" when calling a.volume. What is happening is the following:

- You call a.volume(2,3,4). The method returns 24, but the value is not stored anywhere.
- You then define double v, and try and set it to *a variable called* a.volume. This is because you do not have parenthesis "()" at the end of the v=... assignment statement.

There are a couple ways you may fix this. One way is:

```
double v = a.volume(2,3,4)
```

Another way is to save the value when a.volume is called in the class called method.

```
class Method
{   
  double volumeValue
  double volume(double w,double h,double d)
  {
    volumeValue = h * w * d;
  }
}
```

Then change v=a.volume to v=a.volumeValue. This way, Java sets volumeValue when you call a.volume(2,3,4), then v=a.volumeValue asks Java to return the value you last stored.